# Двуликая кнопка

Tags: php, html, javascript

Ну, суть в том, что у нас есть ссылка: **бе-бе**, 
когда мы на нее нажимаем, она меняет свое имя на: **ба-ба** и при этом каждое название клавиши делает свое действие, например, клавиша **бе-бе** делает так:

```
mysql_auery("UPDATE users SET buttons='бе-бе' where id='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
```

а клавиша **ба-ба** делает так:

```
mysql_auery("UPDATE users SET buttons='ба-ба' where id='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Весёлый сайт получится. =)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Вот мы и добрались до корованов.
Баранов программируешь?

HTML:

```
<button type='button' id='babe'>ба-ба</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#babe').click(function(){

var button_babe = $(this);
$.post('babe_script.php',{val:$(this).html()},function(){
   if(button_babe.html()=='ба-ба'){
     button_babe.html('бе-бе');
   }else{
     button_babe.html('ба-ба');
   }
});
```

});

PHP:

```
mysql_auery("UPDATE users SET buttons='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['val'])."' where id='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
```